# How to deal with command line arguments in Java

Tags: java, design-patterns

Suppose I have a simple program which takes argument input in one of the following forms

do1 inputLocation outputLocation

do2 inputLocation outputLocation

do3 [30 or 60 or 90] inputLocation outputLocation

do4 [P D or C] inputLocation outputLocation

do5 [G H I] inputLocation outputLocation

I also have 5 functions with the same names in the program that I need to call. So far I thought of doing it this way (In 'semi pseudocode')

```
static void main(String[] args)
{
    if (args.length == 3)
        processTriple(args);
    if (args.length == 4)
        processQuadruple(args);
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("dasdhklasdha");
}
```

where the process functions look like this

```
processDouble(String args[])
{
    String operation = "args[0]";
    Location input = getInput(args[1]);
    Location output = getInput(args[2]);
    if (operation.equals("do1"))
        do1(input,output);
    if (operation.equals("do2"))
        do2(input,output);
    ... etc
}
```

The way I'm doing it doesn't seem very extensible. If a function's arguments change, or new functions are added it seems like this would be a pain to maintain.
What's the "best" way of going about something like this

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java library for parsing command-line parameters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200054/java-library-for-parsing-command-line-parameters)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

at this point I would use [commons-cli](http://commons.apache.org/cli/usage.html) or [jargs](http://jargs.sourceforge.net/). Unless you are trying to do something really special with arguments I would say focus in the real business of your app and don't deal with the mess of the application arguments

Answer (score 3):

Use a command line parsing library.

Answer (score 2):

Ive used [JOpt Simple](http://pholser.github.com/jopt-simple/) in the past with great results. It lets you abstract away the command line arg mess, and keep a really clean update-able list of arguments. An added benefit is it will generate the help output that standard command line utilities have.

Heres a quick example:

```
private void runWithArgs (String[] args) {
    OptionParser parser = getOptionParser ();
    OptionSet options = null;

    try {
        options = parser.parse (args);
    }
    catch (OptionException e) {
        log.error ("Sorry the command line option(s): " + e.options () + 
                    " is/are not recognized. -h for help.");
        return;
    }

    if (options.has ("h")) {
        try {
            log.info ("Help: ");
            parser.printHelpOn (System.out);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            log.error ("Trying to print the help screen." + e.toString ());
        }
        return;
    }

    if (options.has ("i")) {
        defaultHost = (String) options.valueOf ("i");
    }

    if (options.has ("p")) {
        defaultPort = (Integer) options.valueOf ("p");
    }

    if (options.has ("q")) {
        String queryString = (String) options.valueOf ("q");

        log.info ("Performing Query: " + queryString);
        performQuery (queryString, defaultHost, defaultPort);
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've used [args4j](http://java.net/projects/args4j/) with successful results before as well.

Just another option.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Cédric Beust's [JCommander](http://jcommander.org/) library

> Because life is too short to parse command line parameters

I even creatively violate the original intent of the library to parse NMEA 0183 sentences like **$GPRTE** as follows:

```
import java.util.List;

import com.beust.jcommander.Parameter;
import com.beust.jcommander.internal.Lists;

public class GPRTE {
    @Parameter
    public List<String> parameters = Lists.newArrayList();

    @Parameter(names = "-GPRTE", arity = 4, description = "GPRTE")
    public List<String> gprte;
}
```

Code snippet that processes NMEA 0183 sentence **$GPRTE** from `$GPRTE,1,1,c,*37` into `-GPRTE 1 1 c *37` to comply with JCommander parsing syntax:

```
/**
 * <b>RTE</b> - route message<p>
 * Processes each <b>RTE</b> message received from the serial port in following format:<p>$GPRTE,d1,d2,d3,d4<p>Example: $GPRTE,1,1,c,*37
 * @param sequences result of {@link #Utils.process(String)} method
 * @see <a href="http://www.gpsinformation.org/dale/nmea.htm#RTE">http://www.gpsinformation.org/dale/nmea.htm#RTE<a><p>*/
public static void processGPRTE(final String command){
    final String NMEA_SENTENCE = "GPRTE";
    final String PARAM = "\u0001";
    final String DOLLAR = "\u0004";
    final String COMMA = "\u0005";

    String parsedString = command;

    if (parsedString.contains("$"+NMEA_SENTENCE)){

        parsedString = parsedString.replaceAll("\\$", DOLLAR+PARAM);
        parsedString = parsedString.replaceAll(",", COMMA);

        System.out.println("GPRTE: " + parsedString);

        String[] splits = parsedString.split(DOLLAR);
        for(String info: splits){

            if (info.contains(PARAM+NMEA_SENTENCE)) {
                info = info.replaceFirst(PARAM, "-");

                System.out.println("GPRTE info: " + info);


                String[] args = info.split(COMMA);

                GPRTE cmd = new GPRTE();
                new JCommander(cmd, processEmptyString(args));
                List<String> message = cmd.gprte;

                String data1 = SerialOutils.unescape(message.get(0));
                System.out.println("GPRTE: data1 = " + data1);

                String data2 = SerialOutils.unescape(message.get(1));
                System.out.println("GPRTE: data2 = " + data2);

                String data3 = SerialOutils.unescape(message.get(2));
                System.out.println("GPRTE: data3 = " + data3);

                String data4 = SerialOutils.unescape(message.get(3));
                System.out.println("GPRTE: data4 = " + data4);

                System.out.println("");

            }
        }
    }
}
```